# Squared integral in proof on importance sampling

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to discover the wonders of importance sampling in an open course [pdf](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/mc/Ch-var-is.pdf) from Stanford. In p.5 they claim to use easy rearrangement from:

$$\int \frac{(f(x)p(x)-\mu q(x))^2}{q(x)} dx$$ 
To
$$\int \frac{(f(x)p(x))^2}{q(x)} dx - \mu^2 $$

Where

$$ \mu = \int f(x)p(x) dx$$

I don't know how they do it using simple arrangements. Also it's hard to find how to calculate $\mu^2$ in terms of $f$ and $p$, such that you can make one big integral out of it. No integration rule yet found for:

$$ \left(\int g(x)dx \right)^2 = ...$$

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to $$Var[X] = \int (x-\mu)^2 dx = \int x^2 dx - \left(\int x dx \right)^2$$

I think?

Anyway

$$\int \frac{(fp-\mu q)^2}{q} dx$$

$$= \int \frac{(fp)^2-2(fp)(\mu q)+(\mu q)^2}{q} dx$$

$$= \int \frac{(fp)^2}{q} + \frac{-2(fp)(\mu q)}{q} + \frac{(\mu q)^2}{q} dx$$

$$= \int \frac{(fp)^2}{q} + -2(fp)(\mu) + \mu^2 q dx$$

$$= \int \frac{(fp)^2}{q} dx + \int -2(fp)(\mu) dx + \int \mu^2 qdx$$

$$= \int \frac{(fp)^2}{q} dx + -2\mu\int (fp) dx + \mu^2 \int qdx$$

$$= \int \frac{(fp)^2}{q} dx -2\mu^2 + \mu^2 \int qdx$$

$$= \int \frac{(fp)^2}{q} dx -2\mu^2 + \mu^2$$

Not sure why the last line follows, if it does, because $q$ is said to be a pdf on $\mathbb R^d$ while the integral is taken over $D \subseteq \mathbb R^d$